# JPA cross unidirectional OneToOne

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

I have two entity-classes A and B. For A there is only one instance of class B. Through a lifecicle of application I need to create new instnace of B for A. But for history log I need to store previous instance of B with links to an this A instance. So I created next mapping:

```
@Entity
class A {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="B_ID")
    B b;
}

@Entity
class B {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="A_ID")
    A a;
}
///////
CREATE TABLE A_TABLE (ID uuid, B_ID uuid, FOREIGN KEY (B_ID) REFERENCES B_TABLE(ID));
CREATE TABLE B_TABLE (ID uuid, A_ID uuid, FOREIGN KEY (A_ID) REFERENCES A_TABLE(ID));
```

I already have some correct data in my tables, but each time, when I trying to get any instance of A class, the b field is null. So, what am I doing wrong?

**UPD_0**
Ok, here what I'm realy dealing with:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseUuidEntity {
     @Id
     @Column(name = "ID")
     @Persistent
     protected UUID id;
}

@MappedSuperclass
public class StandartEntity extends BaseUuidEntity { ... }
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity extends BaseUuidEntity { ... }
@Entity(name = "CardEntity")
@Table(name = "TBL_CARD")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "CARD_TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@DiscriminatorValue("0")
public class CardEntity extends AbstractEntity { ... }

@Entity("aEntity")
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
@Table(name = "A_TABLE")
class A extends CardEntity { 
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="B_ID")
    B b;
    public String getBName() {
        return b.getName(); // NullPointerException
    }
}
@Entity("bEntity")
@Table(name = "B_TABLE")
class B extends StandartEntity {
    @Column(name="name")
    String name;
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

-- A_TABLE (ID, B_ID)
'41a2647d-2ef6-f507-92ee-bff0f784b6f3', '5d3c66da-b377-11e4-bc9c-1008b124eacf'
-- B_TABLE (ID, A_TABLE, NAME)
'5d3c66da-b377-11e4-bc9c-1008b124eacf', '41a2647d-2ef6-f507-92ee-bff0f784b6f3', 'Some text'
```

I'm getting all A entities (in my case - it's one)

```
select e from aEntity e
```

and trying to get name of b entity in each of them, but getting nullpointer, cause b is null;

Comment: How do you get the instance of class A? Can you show your code?

Comment: Just simple query by Id:
Query q = em.createQuery("select e from my.package.A e where e.id=:id");
q.setParameter("id", needed_uuid);
q.getSingleResult();

Comment: That code looks fine, so the issue must be with something you're not showing. Do you have any @Id annotations in your entities? Can you show them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it will make any difference, but try changing the code in `getBName()` to use the getter instead of directly referencing the instance variable `b`:

```
public String getBName() {
    return getB().getName();
}
```

instead of:

```
public String getBName() {
    return b.getName(); // NullPointerException
}
```

I suspect that this could be the issue because JPA implementations create proxies for entities, which are usually subclasses of your entities, and these proxies override your getters and setters. So if you don't use the getter it could be that the instance variable does not get initialized properly.

Comment: Nope, sorry, still same null. But, actualy, you give me an Idea so i've tried to set @Access(AccessType.FIELD) for A.b field and got this exception on build:
Field "my.package.A.b" with "explicit field access" is not compatible with "implicit field access" used by its declaring class.
I dunno, maybe it'll give some other idea for you.

Comment: I solved it! Actualy, yeah, you was damn right about implementation thing. In my case it was framework "feature" - I needed to add this feild in view, that used in my screen. Thank you, man!

Answer (score -1):

you need mappedBy anotation: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne
to inform java who is in charge of this relationship and when the 'foreign'id' is storred. You also need the foreign key in only one of the entities not both!

Comment: But I need both! I need to store previous instances of B for a some instance of A class. And I need to determinate working instance of B for an A instance.
And mappedBy sets bidirectional relationsship, but as I wrote I need two unidirectional relationsships.

Comment: @Zielu He doesn't want to do a bidirectional relation, he wants two separate unidirectional relations.